# Unable to view record using force:recordView in Salesforce Site

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com-sites

I have used force:recordView, in a Lightning component which is embedded inside a VF page. If I use this component I am able to see force:recordView, but when used on salesforce site its coming blank.

Salesforce Record Page
[image]

Salesforce Site
[image]

I have provided all possible details in code:

VF PAGE:

```
<apex:includeLightning />
<script src="https://mydomain_path/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
<div id="lightning" />
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:SupportPOrtalSiteApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:SupportPortalSiteCMP",
                {},
                "lightningcmp",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log('>>>>> App is hosted');
                });
    }
);
</script>
<div id="content">
    <div id="lightningcmp" />
</div>
```

[image]

Please let me know how to make this work.

Comment: Does your Site Guest User have the correct Record-Level Access to view this record? You will likely need to configure guest site sharing rules if you have not done so.

Comment: In the profile of the site, I have given Read and create access for the Case object. Also, the case record I am trying to view is having guest user as the owner.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please do not include your code as a screenshot. This makes it hard to read/manipulate for some people. You can [edit] your post to fix this, and use the `{}` button to format the code as a code block.

Comment: Sure will take care of this, and update this. Please help if anyone knows the solution.